# JS Parameter Issue

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script the loads in a certain iframe based on the url parameters. So if the url ends in ?game=game1, the url linked to game1 will load.

Now I also had some games that load in via scripts instead of iframes. When I attempted to make the same thing but for scripts, it errors. If there is no parameters, it shows a blank page (which is normal) but if you have ?game=game1, a browser popup shows saying ERROR: Please provide a 'game' argument!. Once you press okay on the popup, the console logs that the game has been loaded, but it has not.

This is not affected by any external factors like anti-hotlinking or browser cache, as they load fine on a blank page.

Broken Script-Game Loader: https://justbengames.xjustben.repl.co/pages/1/2.html?game=basketball_legend

Working iframe-game Loader: https://justbengames.xjustben.repl.co/pages/1/1.html?game=drift_hunters

Ive tried many different discord servers and different AIs, but nothing. So is this even possible to achive?

Desired behaviour: to load in a script with no errors

Code:

```html
<script>

    // Function to parse URL parameters
    function getUrlParameter(name) {
      name = name.replace(/[[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
      var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
      var results = regex.exec(location.search);
      return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    }

    // Get the "game" parameter from the URL
    var gameParameter = getUrlParameter('game');

    // Define the content sources and scripts for different games
    var gameSettings = {
      alien_invaders: {
        src: 'https://cdn.htmlgames.com/embed.js?game=AlienInvaders2&amp;bgcolor=white',
      },
      traffic_racer: {
        src: 'https://cdn.htmlgames.com/embed.js?game=TrafficRacer&amp;bgcolor=white',
      },
      tictactoe: {
        src: 'https://cdn.htmlgames.com/embed.js?game=TicTacToe&amp;bgcolor=white',
      },
      tetris_fun: {
        src: 'https://cdn.htmlgames.com/embed.js?game=TetrisFun&amp;bgcolor=white',
      },
      tapman: {
        src: 'https://cdn.htmlgames.com/embed.js?game=Tapman&amp;bgcolor=white',
      },
      bloons_td_4: {
        src: 'https://cdn2.addictinggames.com/addictinggames-content/ag-assets/content-items/html5-games/bloonstowerdefense4/index.html',
      },
      basketball_legend: {
        src: 'https://cdn.htmlgames.com/embed.js?game=BasketballLegend&amp;bgcolor=white',
      },
      table_soccer: {
        src: 'https://cdn.htmlgames.com/embed.js?game=TableSoccer&amp;bgcolor=white',
      },
      swipe_a_car: {
        src: 'https://cdn.htmlgames.com/embed.js?game=SwipeACar&amp;bgcolor=white',
      },
      simon_says: {
        src: 'https://cdn.htmlgames.com/embed.js?game=SimonSays&amp;bgcolor=white',
      },
      neon_pinball: {
        src: 'https://cdn.htmlgames.com/embed.js?game=NeonPinball&amp;bgcolor=white',
      },
      ice_blocks: {
        src: 'https://cdn.htmlgames.com/embed.js?game=IceBlocks&amp;bgcolor=white',
      },
      color_circle: {
        src: 'https://cdn.htmlgames.com/embed.js?game=ColorCircle&amp;bgcolor=white',
      },
      search_the_sands: {
        src: 'https://cdn.htmlgames.com/embed.js?game=SearchTheSands&amp;bgcolor=white',
      },
      minesweeper: {
        src: 'https://cdn.htmlgames.com/embed.js?game=Minesweeper&amp;bgcolor=white',
      },
      bubble_spinner: {
        src: 'https://cdn.htmlgames.com/embed.js?game=BubbleSpinner&amp;bgcolor=white',
      },
      // Add other game settings here...
    };

    // Function to load content based on the "game" parameter
    function loadContent() {
      var gameParameter = getUrlParameter('game');
      var game = gameSettings[gameParameter];

      if (game) {
        var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
        scriptElement.src = game.src;
        scriptElement.onload = function () {
          // Script loaded successfully
          console.log('Script loaded successfully.');
        };
        scriptElement.onerror = function () {
          // Error loading the script
          console.error('Error loading the script.');
        };

        var contentContainer = document.getElementById('contentContainer');
        contentContainer.innerHTML = '';
        contentContainer.appendChild(scriptElement);
      } else {
        // Handle the case where the game parameter is not found
        // You can display an error message or take appropriate action here.
        console.error('Game parameter not found.');
      }
    }

    loadContent();
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You'll need to create the minimum sample of code which demonstrates the problem you're seeing, and include that here, in your question.  Please have a read of the tour and the help docs, start with  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Instead of using a regex, simply use a [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) object to get the query parameter: `(new URL(url)).searchParams.get('game')`.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you're over complicating it. Why create a game object with one property? If this is a static list and hardcoding a number for a url is viable, I would go that route. I don't like to do string matching.

```
 var games = [
        { name: 'Alien Invaders', value: 0, src: 'https://cdn.htmlgames.com/embed.js?game=AlienInvaders2&amp;bgcolor=white' },
    ];
```

That way you're not trying to use regex to parse a url.
Instead you can do something like...

```
var game = games.find(x => x.value == 0);
```

It may also behoove you to set a width and height to the element that you've created. It might not happen in a smart way otherwise. You should create all your styling elements in a custom css class and then just applying the class after creating the iframe.